# xpath expression to match text ending with a variable

Tags: java, regex, xpath

I have an XML with entities like this :

```
<Entity>
    <Name>Lwresd_Dns_Server|LwresdDnsServer</Name>
 </Entity   

<Entity>
   <Name>Lwresd_Dns_Server_Data|LwresdDnsServerData</Name>
</Entity>
```

My xpath expression is
        `XPathExpression expr = xpath1.compile("//Entity[matches(Name,'" +line+ "')]");`

where line is a variable with value `LwresdDnsServer`.

The above xpath expression matches both entities , where I need it to match only the first one, i.e

```
Lwresd_Dns_Server|LwresdDnsServer
```

How should I frame the expression  to do that ??

Comment: You might be interested in an XPath 1.0 expression that implements what the XPath 2.0 function `ends-with()` does. I provide this in my answer.

Comment: Thanks.ends-with() function suits my need.

Comment: jumov, In this case you are better off with my solution. The currently accepted solution assumes that `Name` doesnt contain the `$` character -- such assumptions maynot be always true and needs verification every time one wants to use this technique. On the other side, the simple XPath one-liner from my answer is generally true and doesn't rely on any such assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this should do the trick:

```
XPathExpression expr = 
    xpath1.compile("//Entity[contains(concat('|', Name, '|'),'|" +line+ "|')]");
```

This compares the entity Name enclosed in `|`s with the variable name enclosed in `|`s, so you get something like:

```
contains('|Lwresd_Dns_Server|LwresdDnsServer|', '|LwrestDnsServer|') => Yes
contains('|Lwresd_Dns_Server_Data|LwresdDnsServerData|', '|LwrestDnsServer|') => No
```

And resultingly, only the first of the two Entities is selected.

If you **only** want to find entities that *end with* `line` (and not just those that contain an exact match for it), then you can do this (assuming the values are guaranteed to not contain the character `$` - if there's the possibility it would contain a `$`, you should choose a different delimiter that it definitely won't contain, or use Dimitre Novatchev's answer to this question):

```
XPathExpression expr = 
    xpath1.compile("//Entity[contains(concat(Name, '$'),'" +line+ "$')]");
```

I haven't used the `matches()` function in XPath (it's not supported in XPath 1.0), but I suspect the following would also work for finding a value at the end of an Entity name, if your XPath evaluator supports `matches()`:

```
XPathExpression expr = 
    xpath1.compile("//Entity[matches(Name,'" +line+ "$')]");
```

Here, `$` is the RegEx symbol for the end of a string.

Comment: The entity Name is not  enclosed in |s. Only one pipe is present in the Name text.  The xpath expression has to ensure that the pattern 'LwrestDnsServer' is at the end of the Name , something like a $ in a regex.What should be the syntax for that ?

Comment: Yes, I know the Entity name isn't enclosed in |s. My formula is checking whether the Entity name with |s appended at the beginning and end contains |line|.  So are you saying that you will **only** be comparing line against the last value in Entity, and not, for example, "Lwresd_Dns_Server"?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am trying to do.

Comment: In that case, one or both of my second two examples should work.

Comment: JLRishe, This solution only works if it is guaranteed that the `$` character isn't contained in `Name`. A simple XPath 1.0 implementation of `ends-with()` exists, that doesn't depend on any such assumptions.

Comment: @DimitreNovatchev Yes, that's true.  I had meant to mention that, but it appears that I didn't.  I've added a cautionary note above.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is an XPath 1.0 expression that implements what the XPath 2.0 function `ends-with($s, $t)` does**:

```
substring($s, string-length($s) - string-length($t) +1) = $t
```

**You can substitute `$s` and `$t` above with specific strings**.